# Kafka as Messaging queue in Microservices

Tags: multithreading, apache-kafka, microservices, kafka-consumer-api

To give you background of the question, i am considering Kafka as a channel for inter service communication between micro services. Most of my micro services would have web nature (Either Web server/ REST server/ SOAP server to communicate with existing endpoints).

At some point i need asynchronous channel between micro services so i a considering Kafka as the message broker.

In my scenario, i have RESTfull microservice once its job is done, it that pushes messages to Kafka queue. Then another micro service which is also web server (embedded tomcat) with small REST layer would consume those messages.

Reason for considering messaging queue is that even if my receiving micro service is down for some reason, all my incoming message would be added to queue and data flow wont be disturbed. Another reason is that Kafka is persistent queue.

Typically, Kafka consumer are multi threaded.

Question is that, receiving micro service being web server, i am concerned about creating user threads in a servlet container managed environment. It might work. But considering the fact that user created threads are bad within web application, i am confused. So what would be your approach in this scenario.

Please suggest.

Comment: Why not break the consumer web service into two components, one purely for reading from the data store that a separate Kafka consumer writes to?

Comment: not clear how you route your message to consumer if you have multiple instances of the same consumer?